Error connecting S3 Minio Object Store to Artifactory
This is another question. But the essence is the same no connection to S3 MINIO BINARYSTORE. But at the moment another very strange error. Approximately DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature...but there are no files with DOCTYPE anywhere.
binarystore.xml file:
<config version="2">
   <chain>
        <provider id="cache-fs" type="cache-fs">
            <provider id="s3-storage-v3" type="s3-storage-v3"/>
        </provider>
   </chain>
   <provider id="s3-storage-v3" type="s3-storage-v3">
       <endpoint>https://s3-site.com</endpoint>
       <bucketName>test</bucketName>
       <path></path>
       <region>site</region>
       <identity>username</identity>
       <credential>password</credential>
       <usePresigning>true</usePresigning>
       <signatureExpirySeconds>600</signatureExpirySeconds>
       <maxConnections>50</maxConnections>
       <connectionTimeout>10000</connectionTimeout>
   </provider>
   <provider type="cache-fs" id="cache-fs">
       <maxCacheSize>5000000000</maxCacheSize>
   </provider>
</config>

Error encountered when starting Artifactory, I also added DEBUG logs:
2024-10-22T13:28:33.982Z [jfrt ] [DEBUG] [408dbd5b6a3d51a ] [c.a.i.SdkSSLSocket:31         ] [art-init            ] - created: test.s3-site.com/172.17.14.250:443
2024-10-22T13:28:34.001Z [jfrt ] [DEBUG] [408dbd5b6a3d51a ] [c.a.r.ClockSkewAdjuster:179   ] [art-init            ] - Reported server date (from 'Date' header): Tue, 22 Oct 2024 13:28:33 GMT
2024-10-22T13:28:34.056Z [jfrt ] [DEBUG] [408dbd5b6a3d51a ] [.m.t.XmlResponsesSaxParser:160] [art-init            ] - Parsing XML response document with handler: class com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$AccessControlListHandler
2024-10-22T13:28:34.063Z [jfrt ] [WARN ] [408dbd5b6a3d51a ] [ifactoryApplicationContext:288] [art-init            ] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'blobInfoServiceImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/artifactory/WEB-INF/lib/artifactory-addons-common-7.59.13.jar!/org/artifactory/addon/common/blobinfo/BlobInfoServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'replicatorServiceImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/artifactory/WEB-INF/lib/artifactory-addons-common-7.59.13.jar!/org/artifactory/addon/common/replicator/ReplicatorServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'artifactDistributionStatusWriterServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'taskService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'taskServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'addonsManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'addonsManagerImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setEntitlementService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'JFConnectServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setAccessService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accessServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setCentralConfigService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'centralConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setBuildService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'buildServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setUploadService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'uploadServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setTrafficService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'trafficServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setRepositoryService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'storageService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'storageServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setBinaryStore' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'artifactoryBinaryServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setBinaryService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'binaryInternalService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to parse XML document with handler class com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$AccessControlListHandler
2024-10-22T13:28:34.076Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [408dbd5b6a3d51a ] [ctoryContextConfigListener:126] [art-init            ] - Application could not be initialized: DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" set to true.

